# Can I access other directive from within a structural directive?

Tags: angular

I am using the structural directive `*myCheckbox` to wrap every content child of `my-checkbox-group` in some html.

I also have an directive `MyFormControlDirective` that adds a label and a bunch of other input variables and getters to form controls.

I would like to access this directive from within the structural `MyCheckboxDirective`'s code.

Is this possible and if so, how?

---

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myCheckbox]'
})
export class MyCheckboxDirective {
  readonly myControl: MyFormControlDirective; // How do i get this one filled?

  constructor(readonly template: TemplateRef<any>) {}
}
```

---

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[formControlName]'
})
export class MyFormControlDirective {
  @Input() formControlLabel: string;
  ...
}
```

---

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-checkbox-group'
})
export class CheckboxGroupComponent {
  @ContentChildren(MyCheckboxDirective, {descendants: true}) myCheckboxes: QueryList<MyCheckboxDirective>;
}
```

```
<fieldset class="input">
  <div class="input__group--checkbox" *ngFor="let box of myCheckboxes">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="box.template"></ng-container>
    <label class="input__label--checkbox">{{ box.myControl.label }}</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

---

I use it like this:

```
<my-checkbox-group>
  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="agreeThis" *myCheckbox formControlLabel="I agree to this">
  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="agreeThat" *myCheckbox formControlLabel="I agree to that">
</my-checkbox-group>
```